# display pdf file from google drive

Tags: android, pdf, drive

now i'm trying this code
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private String myPdfUrl = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rquwQNdXeds39Rlb32isX3bjYghHitCV/view";

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.ve);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                                 @Override
                                 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                                     view.loadUrl(myPdfUrl);
                                     return true;
                                 }
                             }
    );
    webView.loadUrl(myPdfUrl);

}
```

}

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you try this code to make load PDF

### i also implement in my application

```
String pdfURL = "your url";
webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfURL);
```

Comment: do i must put it also inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading function.?

Comment: i got this validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)